# Rolling Average in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
LotNumber   Device  Measure MeasureDate RowNumber
LotA        DevA    1.1     10/1/15 0:00    1
LotA        DevA    1.2     10/1/15 1:00    1
LotA        DevB    1.1     10/1/15 2:00    2
LotB        DevA    1.3     10/1/15 3:00    3
LotB        DevA    1.4     10/1/15 4:00    3
LotA        DevA    1.2     10/1/15 5:00    4
LotC        DevA    1.3     10/1/15 6:00    5
LotD        DevA    1.5     10/1/15 7:00    6
LotE        DevA    1.1     10/1/15 8:00    7
LotF        DevA    1.2     10/1/15 9:00    8
LotG        DevA    1.3     10/1/15 10:00   9
LotH        DevA    1.4     10/1/15 11:00   10



LotNumber   Device  Measure MeasureDate RowNumber   Rolling Average
LotA        DevA    1.1     10/1/15 0:00    1       Measure Average of RowNumber 1-5
LotA        DevB    1.1     10/1/15 2:00    2       Measure Average of RowNumber 2-6
LotB        DevA    1.3     10/1/15 3:00    3       Measure Average of RowNumber 3-7
LotA        DevA    1.2     10/1/15 5:00    4       Measure Average of RowNumber 4-8
LotC        DevA    1.3     10/1/15 6:00    5       Measure Average of RowNumber 5-9
LotD        DevA    1.5     10/1/15 7:00    6       Measure Average of RowNumber 6-10
LotE        DevA    1.1     10/1/15 8:00    7       Measure Average of RowNumber 7-10
LotF        DevA    1.2     10/1/15 9:00    8       Measure Average of RowNumber 8-10
LotG        DevA    1.3     10/1/15 10:00   9       Measure Average of RowNumber 9-10
LotH        DevA    1.4     10/1/15 11:00   10      Measure Average of RowNumber 10
```

Is it possible to have the second table? I have no idea how to do this. Rolling average of rownumber with intervals of 4. For example, Average of RowNumber 1-5 is the average of all Measure with Rownumber that is ranging from 1-5. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily achieve this through the use of the avg analytic function, something like:

```
with sample_data (LotNumber, Device, Measure, MeasureDate, RowNumber) as
       (select 'LotA', 'DevA', 1.1, to_date('10/1/15 00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 1
 from dual union all
        select 'LotA', 'DevA', 1.2, to_date('10/1/15 01:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 1
 from dual union all
        select 'LotA', 'DevB', 1.1, to_date('10/1/15 02:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 2
 from dual union all
        select 'LotB', 'DevA', 1.3, to_date('10/1/15 03:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 3
 from dual union all
        select 'LotB', 'DevA', 1.4, to_date('10/1/15 04:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 3
 from dual union all
        select 'LotA', 'DevA', 1.2, to_date('10/1/15 05:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 4
 from dual union all
        select 'LotC', 'DevA', 1.3, to_date('10/1/15 06:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 5
 from dual union all
        select 'LotD', 'DevA', 1.5, to_date('10/1/15 07:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 6
 from dual union all
        select 'LotE', 'DevA', 1.1, to_date('10/1/15 08:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 7
 from dual union all
        select 'LotF', 'DevA', 1.2, to_date('10/1/15 09:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 8
 from dual union all
        select 'LotG', 'DevA', 1.3, to_date('10/1/15 10:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 9
 from dual union all
        select 'LotH', 'DevA', 1.4, to_date('10/1/15 11:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 10
 from dual)
select lotnumber,
       device,
       measure,
       measuredate,
       rownumber,
       avg(measure) over (order by rownumber
                          rows between current row and 4 following) rolling_average
from   sample_data
order by rownumber;

LOTNUMBER DEVICE    MEASURE MEASUREDATE         ROWNUMBER ROLLING_AVERAGE
--------- ------ ---------- ------------------ ---------- ---------------
LotA      DevA          1.1 10/01/0015 00:00            1            1.22
LotA      DevA          1.2 10/01/0015 01:00            1            1.24
LotA      DevB          1.1 10/01/0015 02:00            2            1.26
LotB      DevA          1.3 10/01/0015 03:00            3            1.34
LotB      DevA          1.4 10/01/0015 04:00            3             1.3
LotA      DevA          1.2 10/01/0015 05:00            4            1.26
LotC      DevA          1.3 10/01/0015 06:00            5            1.28
LotD      DevA          1.5 10/01/0015 07:00            6             1.3
LotE      DevA          1.1 10/01/0015 08:00            7            1.25
LotF      DevA          1.2 10/01/0015 09:00            8             1.3
LotG      DevA          1.3 10/01/0015 10:00            9            1.35
LotH      DevA          1.4 10/01/0015 11:00           10             1.4
```

N.B. you didn't mention any grouping (eg. per day, per lotnumber, etc) and I used the rownumber column for the ordering - maybe it should have been the measuredate column?). If your requirements are more complex than what you've stated, you'll need to amend the `over ()` clause appropriately.

---

With your additional comment that clarifies your requirements, you can amend the windowing clause to be on range, rather than rows between, like so:

```
with sample_data (LotNumber, Device, Measure, MeasureDate, RowNumber) as
       (select 'LotA', 'DevA', 1.1, to_date('10/1/15 00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 1
 from dual union all
        select 'LotA', 'DevA', 1.2, to_date('10/1/15 01:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 1
 from dual union all
        select 'LotA', 'DevB', 1.1, to_date('10/1/15 02:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 2
 from dual union all
        select 'LotB', 'DevA', 1.3, to_date('10/1/15 03:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 3
 from dual union all
        select 'LotB', 'DevA', 1.4, to_date('10/1/15 04:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 3
 from dual union all
        select 'LotA', 'DevA', 1.2, to_date('10/1/15 05:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 4
 from dual union all
        select 'LotC', 'DevA', 1.3, to_date('10/1/15 06:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 5
 from dual union all
        select 'LotD', 'DevA', 1.5, to_date('10/1/15 07:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 6
 from dual union all
        select 'LotE', 'DevA', 1.1, to_date('10/1/15 08:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 7
 from dual union all
        select 'LotF', 'DevA', 1.2, to_date('10/1/15 09:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 8
 from dual union all
        select 'LotG', 'DevA', 1.3, to_date('10/1/15 10:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 9
 from dual union all
        select 'LotH', 'DevA', 1.4, to_date('10/1/15 11:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 10
 from dual)
select lotnumber,
       device,
       measure,
       measuredate,
       rownumber,
       avg(measure) over (order by rownumber
                          range between current row and 4 following) rolling_average,
       row_number() over (partition by rownumber order by measuredate) rn
from   sample_data
order by rownumber;

LOTNUMBER DEVICE    MEASURE MEASUREDATE            ROWNUMBER ROLLING_AVERAGE         RN
--------- ------ ---------- --------------------- ---------- --------------- ----------
LotA      DevA          1.1 10/01/0015 00:00:00            1      1.22857143          1
LotA      DevA          1.2 10/01/0015 01:00:00            1      1.22857143          2
LotA      DevB          1.1 10/01/0015 02:00:00            2             1.3          1
LotB      DevA          1.3 10/01/0015 03:00:00            3             1.3          1
LotB      DevA          1.4 10/01/0015 04:00:00            3             1.3          2
LotA      DevA          1.2 10/01/0015 05:00:00            4            1.26          1
LotC      DevA          1.3 10/01/0015 06:00:00            5            1.28          1
LotD      DevA          1.5 10/01/0015 07:00:00            6             1.3          1
LotE      DevA          1.1 10/01/0015 08:00:00            7            1.25          1
LotF      DevA          1.2 10/01/0015 09:00:00            8             1.3          1
LotG      DevA          1.3 10/01/0015 10:00:00            9            1.35          1
LotH      DevA          1.4 10/01/0015 11:00:00           10             1.4          1
```

Note that I've included the "rn" column, because I wasn't sure if you wanted to filter out the "duplicate" rownumber rows or not - if you do, then you'll need to add an outer query that filters on rn = 1.

N.B. It would have been helpful if you had included the actual output values you were expecting to see in the rolling average column rather than just the logic, so that we could compare our results with it.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much but my requirement is a little bit more complex than that. I don't even know if its possible. The grouping of average is not between number of rows, but between the values of the RowNumber column. So when I need the average of rownumber 1-5, I will need to average all rows with rownumber VALUE of 1 to 5. in our sample, that would be 7 rows. 1,1,2,3,3,4,5. Please tell me if its possible.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include something I hope is what you're after.